# Authorization Rules Missing in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I added the role URL Authorization but I still don't get this option clicking on my web site, do I need to restart anything like IIS, the server etc

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I had to close down server manager and re-open it to appear.

Comment: You can also accomplish the same thing by disconnecting and reconnecting to the server, without actually closing server manager.